# Symfony2.1/FOSUserBundle - change the login form route to the homepage route (path: /)

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a symfony 2.1 project using FOSUserBundle. The bundle is installed correctly. All the functionalities work properly using the default /login form.

But now I want to change the login form route to be the same as the homepage (path: /).

I tried:

changing the **security.yml - login_path**:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

and the **access_control** to:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }        
    - { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

When I try to access the homepage it enters a infinite redirect (I assume)

> The page isn't redirecting properly  Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete.

Also couldn't find anything to troubleshoot this behaviour inside the FOSUserBundle documentation.

In short words: I want the first_page to act as login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a redirect loop.

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }    #1
- { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }  #2
- { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } #3
- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }                      #4
- { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }                            #5
- { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }          #6
```

This happens because first, you are telling access controll in #5 requires **ROLE_USER** *BEFORE* you tell it that it also requires **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** (both 5th and 6th rules match)

Access control is order sensitive, the rules apply in the order they are defined, try:

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # NOTE THE $
- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }        
- { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I moved the rule

```
- { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

to the begining so it matches before

```
- { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: thanks you for the fast answer, but unfortunately, it doesn't work as I wish. for example I can access my /demo-test path even if I am logged out :\

Comment: is there any way you can change the route from /* to be /? like an regular expresion (instead of 0-any character to be 1-any character) ?

Comment: They all area Regex so you can do pretty much whatever you want. I edited my answer, '^/$' means "the route should start, then contain **/** and then end" so it should work and not match anything else but the home page

Comment: oh.. this works. Thank you. 1 more questions: where can i found these rules (doesn't seem to be the basic regex expressions i use in php).

Comment: They are just regexes, if they match the route, the rule will be applied, just the first rule that matches is applied and the rest skipped. The only thing you need to do is to create that REGEX to match whatever set of routes you want, although the most common will always be **^/some-area**, **^/some/page$**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change on your security.yml :
`login_path: /` to `login_path: /login`

And your access_control :

```
{ path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }    #1
{ path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }  #2
{ path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } #3
{ path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }                      #4
```

Hope this help !